# Read a remote file from a specific node in my cluster using Spark Submit

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

It exists a possibility to get a specific file from a specific node executed from a spark-submit?

My first approach was getting the list of every nodes in my cluster using spark-submit by a socket, that was the first part, now, I want to connect directly to a specific node to get a specific file, this file is not a HDFS file is a local file on that remote node.

I cannot use a ftp because I do not have those credentials, they perform a direct connection.

textfile is not working, I would like to specify the node name and path of the file.

Ej.

> textfile(remoteNodeConnectedToMyCluster:///path/file.txt)

I hope been clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to accomplish that, short of installing a server (e.g. FTP, HTTP) on the node to serve the file or running a script on the node to copy it to a distributed file system (e.g. HDFS).

Note that a properly specified URL would have the form `protocol://host/path/to/file.txt`.